# Rendering: only <body> content visible on some pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, html, render

Almost all the page's render correct. Currently i have 1 (product) page which shows only the content of the  tag. When i view the source, the html,body, head tags are all gone (both opening and closing tag)

Instead of:

```
<html><head></head><body>Content</body></html>
```

All i get is

```
Content
```

When i clear all cache this problem is gone but then there will be another page with this problem so don't tell me to just refresh the cache ;)

When i change the product data in the backend, the changes are visible on the frontend but the problem remains. The content is correct.

This is the state of the project:

- all caching is enabled
- caching to redis cache (default+full page)
- production mode
- javascript NOT combined
- css minified AND combined
- static files are signed
- the product does not have design updates or invalid content (it's not related to this product)
- indexing is up to date
- there is nothing significant in the log files
- browser cache is disabled, CTRL+F5, ...

Edit: add screenshots
[image]

Comment: Share your screen shot please.

Comment: I added a screenshot but don't think it shows you any useful information

Comment: When i change "layout" to "empty" or "1 column", there is nothing wrong. When i change it back to "no layout update", the problem is back.